# Pro ASP.net MVC Framework code question

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The following line on page 110 of [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210079) does not make sense to me:

```
string links = ((HtmlHelper)null).PageLinks(2, 3, i => "Page" + i);
```

I don't understand what is the `null` doing in the above statement?

I was unable to do .. `HtmlHelper.PageLinks(....)`

Is the PageLinks Method an extension method?

Comment: That cast seems to be for getting the VS Intellicence and fool the server compiler haha ... checkout if you have the reference (<% Refernce) to that extension method you are using in there ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's invoking an extension method on a null "instance" of an HtmlHelper. Probably there's no HtmlHelper in scope and the author can't be bothered to create one. The `PageLinks` method itself will not require a reference to an HtmlHelper, so effectively the author is passing `null`.

If you think about the signature of the extension method:

```
public static string PageLinks
    (this HtmlHelper helper, int val1, int val2, Func<someType,string> func)
```

It simply means that the parameter helper will be passed as `null`. It's a weird construct though, particularly in a book. It's got a really hacky smell to it.

The call could be restated (perhaps more clearly) as:

```
AuthorsHtmlExtensionsClass.PageLinks(null, 2, 3, i => "Page" + i)
```

Just reading though my MVC2 copy of the same book, (it's the end of the SportsStore application, right?), Steven has changed the code to:

```
HtmlHelper html=null;
...
html.PageLinks(...)
```

Which I suppose is a little clearer.